# Como usar os módulos e o decorador NgModule?

Tags: angular, angular-module, decorator-pattern

Tenho dúvidas de como usar os decoradores do `NgModule`. Quais são e pra que servem?

Como criar um módulo separado para carregar uma ou mais bibliotecas e componentes?

Por exemplo, um para carregar as dependências e elementos do Material Design, outro para carregar e iniciar o AngularFire e outro para carregar determinados componentes da aplicação

Comment: Amigo, se você seguir esse guia, acredito que todas suas dúvidas vão ser esclarecidas.
https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Módulos são a principal forma de **organização** e **arquitetura** que o angular fornece. Sendo assim como qualquer coisa relacionada a arquitetura depende principalmente **de cada projeto**. Mas de acordo com a documentação official e ha alguns guidelines gerais recomendados como uma arquitetura **por features**.

Primerio vamos ver os campos existente nos modulos:

**Obrigatórios:**

**imports** - > Onde vc importa outros módulos que seu modulo depende.

**declarations** -> Declarações dos componentes que estão dentro do seu modulo.

**Opicionais**

**exports** -> Declarações dos componentes sera visíveis para outros módulos que importarem este modulo.

**providers** -> Declarações dos services a partir do angular 6 vc pode declarar o service pra ter um escopo global dentro dele deixando essa opção meio inutil pra aplicacoes mais novas.

Você tem sempre o **app.module** que o modulo principal que carrega outros módulos e suas rotas principais. Tudo que for carregado aqui terá um escopo **global** na sua aplicação mas deixara mais lento ao inciar.

O ponto de ter vários módulos e justamente poder ter uma aplicação **extremamente eficiente** onde cada modulo so usa o que realmente necessita. Por exemplo nem todo modulo necessita de forms por exemplo. Dessa forma e com a ajuda de **lazy loading** o angular consegue deixar sua aplicação bem leve.

Sendo assim vamos ver um exemplo:

Se vc tiver uma feature produtos que tem por exemplo uma rota /produtos que permite listar e inserir produtos faz sentido ter um produtos module onde vc carrega esses componentes(lista-produto, inserir-produto) e este seu modulo so sera carregando quando seu usuário entrar em /produtos o que e bem util para aplicacoes grandes.

Outro ponto interessante são **shared modules** ou modulos compartilhados que normalmente contem componentes exclusivamentes de vizualizacao (so contem inputs e outputs e nenhuma logica de negocio). Neste shared modules vc pode ter por exemplo um ter cards module que pode no nosso exemplo teria uma card de produto e onde esse modulo for importado vc tera acesso a esse componente. Eu recomendo ter varios desses shared modules assim vc pode ter um botoes.module, cards.module ou qualquer coisa genérica que vc imaginar. Ajudando a compartilhar o código e dando a **consistência** a visualização do seu projeto.